# call command with absolute path using bash variable

Tags: bash

I'm using android sdk and I need to use the `android` command in my script, the file I need is in the following folder: `/my_downloads/android-sdk/tools/android`.
I tried to do this in my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ANDROID_PATH="/my_downloads/android-sdk/tools/android/"
"$ANDROID_PATH"android  # etc...
```

but it does not work.
What is the correct way to do that maintaining that path as variable?

Thanks

Comment: Does the `/my_downloads/android-sdk/tools/android/android` file have the execution bit set? Also check whether execution is allowed for the parent file system: `mount | grep noexec`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add folder with executable to your `PATH` as follows:

```
PATH="/my_downloads/android-sdk/tools/:$PATH"
```

And then just use:

```
android
```

Answer (score 0):

Your shell script runs /my_downloads/android-sdk/tools/android/android (which doesn't exist).

It should instead be running /my_downloads/android-sdk/tools/android

```
#!/bin/bash
ANDROID_PATH="/my_downloads/android-sdk/tools/"
"$ANDROID_PATH"android  # etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Good idea is to always see where some file is located.
"whereis" command by default works pretty good for that purpose.

```
$ whereis bash
bash: /bin/bash /etc/bash.bashrc /usr/share/man/man1/bash.1.gz
```